# WPK.TO dividend date

Tags: dividends

Winpak's [press release](https://www.newswire.ca/news-releases/winpak-s-board-of-directors-announces-special-one-time-dividend-832689762.html) notes:

> Winpak Ltd. (TSX: WPK) announces that at a meeting on June 23, 2021, the Company's Board of Directors declared a special one-time dividend of three dollars (Canadian currency) per share. The dividend is payable July 9, 2021 to shareholders of record at the close of business on **July 2, 2021**.

I would expect the price drop about CA$3 after July 2, 2021. July 1 is a holiday for TSX. July 3&4 are weekend. So the drop should happen on July 5, 2021. However, **today (June 30, 2021)** the price dropped by around CA$3. What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it works in the USA and  I believe that it's the same in Canada:

> Declaration date

- The day that the public traded company declares an upcoming dividend payment to stockholders.

> Ex-dividend date

- The first day on which a stockholder can sell their shares and still be entitled to receive the upcoming dividend payment.

> Payment date

- The day which stockholders receive dividend payment.

> Record date

- The day when you must be on the company's books as a stockholder to receive the dividend.  The ex-dividend date is normally set for two business days before the record date.

> Settlement Date

- The day in which the stock ownership transferal is finalized.  Also known as T+2.

> T+2

- Trade Date + 2 business days.  The grace period allowed to settle a trade.  This is the final day to transfer share ownership and money between the parties involved in the stock transaction.

Regarding your position, today is the ex-dividend date which is two days before the record date of Friday, July 2nd.